# if else inside of $_post isset

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a form that is filled out by a sports coach. A coach can have multiple sports they coach and a player can play multiple sports. So if a coach wants to add a player to a team roster I need to check if the player exists and if so then just add the player id to the roster table and not add the player again to the players table. Below is the best representation of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con2, $_POST['email']);

$sql1 = "SELECT id, email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
$result = $con2->query($sql1);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

//here is where I want to just add specific information


} //I have tried if $result == 0 and else if $result == 0


//here is where I would add the user if the email doesn't exist.

}  <-- //I feel like the issue is the if (isset($_POST['submit'])) which end just before this line.
```

So I get mixed results based on where I place the end of the (isset($_POST['submit'])). I am trying to figure out how to retain the $_POST being set but not execute everything within in. I am pretty knew to this so please forgive me if I my question seems basic. Thanks for taking the time to review my question.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**
So I am not having an issue getting the number of rows. The problem is that even if the email exists the user gets duplicated in the user table but in the rest of the tables the user isn't duplicated. Basically everything inside of the (isset($_POST['submit'])) gets run which makes sense since when the form is submitted this evaluates to true.

Essentially I want to run an if else inside of the (isset($_POST['submit'])) without both getting executed if that make sense.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: are you trying to update user that exist in the database? only if he has an email?

Comment: Please stop testing `num_rows` it isn't always reliable - the data always is. If you don't want to look at the results then just `SELECT count(id) FROM users WHERE email='$email'`. And fetch the result - there will _always be one row_ with a count of zero or more. Always test 'real data' everything else can be 'unreliable'. You can always add a ` LIMIT 1` if efficiency is a concern

Comment: @AdiAzarya the relationship is a coach and player. A coach can have multiple sports they coach and a player can play multiple sports. So if a coach wants to add a player to a team roster I need to check if the player exists and if so then just add the player id to the roster table and not add the player again to the players table.

Comment: @RyanVincent thank you for that. Like I said I pretty knew to PHP and what you are saying makes perfect sense. I didn't know count() was an option as I have never seen in before.

Comment: @RyanVincent I have updated my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameterized queries as suggested by @tadman.

However, I'm not going to criticize your codes but suggest trying out the function:

```
mysqli_num_rows($result)
```

This should return number of rows in the result set. Please let us know whether this is what you're seeking.

Comment: I am slowly learning the do and don't methods of PHP so I will be surely working on the correct or best practice methods of writing things. Just trying to get a grasp on things right now honestly.  I will try the mysqli_num_rows and see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Ok @RyanVincent, you needn't to say that again and again. But, I have to agree your solution about using `count($id)` would work in @MBRD case. Generally, I'd like to avoid creation of simple SQL queries as they can become a burden to manage.

Comment: fyi, imo, `num_rows` (I mean any 'indicator of row count' from the database) is unreliable for queries and updates (i.e. it is never  an accurate indicator of 'count of rows' or 'number of rows updated'). imo, Always test `real data` not indicators. You can 'trust' it for inserts and deletes. Nothing else. Example - update a row without changes and the `row count` is zero - even though everything worked correctly.

Comment: @RyanVincent I see what you're doing. Really, you have to remove your comments so that my comment wouldn't make any sense above yours. Don't go shallower than Hal.

Answer (score 0):

i will show you very simple example of mysqli hope it will help you :)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";//YOUR USER NAME!
$password = "password";//YOUR PASSWORD!
$dbname = "myDB"; //YOUR DB NAME!

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if (isset($_POST["save"])){
  $var1 = $_POST['memberID'];   //form parameters
  $var2 = $_POST['firstName']; //form parameters
  $var3 = $_POST['surname'];  //form parameters
  $var4 = $_POST['email'];   //form parameters

  //query example 
  $query = "SELECT ".$var4." FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50";

  if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

you can see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) page. may it will help you to understand how does it work!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
....
$query = "SELECT* FROM City WHERE email=".$var4."";

  if ($result = $conn->query($query))
  {
  if($result != " "){}//the player exist->DO SOMETHING
  else{}//DO SOMETHING//the player not exist->DO SOMETHING
  }
...
```

maybe i didn't understand you well :|